# using fosUserBundle's authentication in separate program

Tags: symfony, encryption, hash, fosuserbundle

I would like to use the hash algorithm from FOSUserBundle in a standalone app.

Here's what I want to do:

-Copy the user table into a standalone app
-Let users use their symfony2 login in my separate app
In order to do this, I need to code a copy of the FOSUserBundles authentication in my app.

So my question is - where can I find this algorithm in the FOSUserBundle codebase? Is it just a md5() together with the user specific salt or how is it constructed?

Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***

So while this would certainly be interesting to know how to do, I am now faced instead with changing the algorithm in FOSUserBundle, so I will have to do it the other way around. And I will open a different topic for that.

Comment: Did you manage using it in your solution, @Matthias? I'm looking for a way to check the authentification of user logged in via symfony in an external script. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question:

Password encoders are part of the Synfony's core, not FOSUserBundle. You may find them in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder`.
To find the correct encoder to use in your custom script look what you have configured for FOSUserBundle.